# How to count a specific nos with ref to specific text in excel

Tags: excel-formula

```
Name     Status
AA        O
BB        C
AA        C
CC        O
DD        C
AA        O
```

How to count tatal Nos of C if name colum contain AA

Comment: I have to admit, I don't understand what exactly you want to know. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help.

Comment: as Tom Sharpe has explained, this is a VERY simple COUNTIFS formula and the answer to this could have been found with a quick search on a search engine or even using Excel's formula search page which explains how each formula works

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"AA",B:B,"C")
```

assuming your data is in columns A & B and you want to check the whole of columns A & B